# Vim quit insert mode when navigate with mapping keys

Tags: vim

In order to move the cursor in insert mode, I add the following key maps in my .vimrc(I use vim 7.3 on Sun OS)

```
inoremap <Alt-h> <Left>
inoremap <Alt-j> <Down>
inoremap <Alt-k> <Up>
inoremap <Alt-l> <Right>
```

When I press the mapping keys, the cursor moves correct, but vim will quit insert mode and switch to normal mode, what's wrong with my vim? I also tried this with my gvim on Windows, it works well. Did I lost any options for the mapping keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some terminal emulators generate escape sequences for meta (alt) characters. `Alt-A` becomes `<esc>a`. This is usually a problem on *nix machines.

You can find out more details here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_meta-keys_that_break_out_of_Insert_mode

Answer (score 1):

It's not a solution, but a workaround to your problem might be

```
inoremap <Alt-h> <c-o>h
inoremap <Alt-j> <c-o>j
inoremap <Alt-k> <c-o>k
inoremap <Alt-l> <c-o>l
```

`:h i_CTRL-O` => `execute one command, return to Insert mode`

If that has the same problem (dropping out of insert mode on Sun OS) the following should work cross platform [unverified claim].

```
inoremap <Alt-h> <esc>i
inoremap <Alt-j> <esc>ja
inoremap <Alt-k> <esc>ka
inoremap <Alt-l> <esc>la
```